# how to insert partial view from another controller in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to insert a partial view from NewsController into HomeController.
In my NewsController

```
public ActionResult LastNewsPatial()
        {
            var lstLastNews = db.Articles.Take(5).OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate).ToList();
            return PartialView(lstLastNews);
        }
```

In Views/News folder i create LastNewsPatial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<mytest.com.Models.Article>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div class="glidecontent">
        <img src="@item.ImageURL" style="float: left; margin-right:21px;" />
        <a href="#" class="title"><strong>@item.Title</strong></a><br /><br />
        @item.Content
    </div>
}
```

In Views/Home/Index.cshtml i insert a LastNewsPatial view

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/News/LastNewsPatial.cshtml")
```

When i run my project then I received a error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

at row

> @foreach (var item in Model)

in **LastNewsPatial.cshtml**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give `.cshtml` in name of view when `rendering` a `view`. Only give name of `PartialView` without `.cshtml` like this.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/LastNewsPatial")
```

You can also use `@Html.Action()` to render your view like this

```
@Html.Action("LastNewsPatial","News")
```

Comment: `Additional information: The partial view '~/Views/News/HotNewsPartial' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.` I received error when I adjust `@Html.Partial("~/Views/News/LastNewsPatial")` again

Comment: Yes because your `path` is not correct. Please correct the `path`.

Comment: the correct my path is `@Html.Partial("~/Views/News/LastNewsPatial")`

Comment: @TienKenji take a look at my answer .. the view has no Model to render .. hence the error. use the method i specified and you'll have what you need.

Comment: Error `Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.` when i use `@Html.Action("LastNewsPatial","News") `

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that the `Model` isn't passed to the view... infact the action isn't even called at all. Set a breakpoint and you'll confirm this.

I think you should be calling `@Html.RenderAction` inside the index instead of `@Html.Partial`.

Instead of `@Html.Partial("~/Views/News/LastNewsPatial.cshtml")`

use

```
@Html.RenderAction("LastNewsPatial","News")
```

or  `@Html.Action("LastNewsPatial","News")`

Comment: when i used `@Html.RenderAction("LastNewsPatial","News")` then I received error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'`

Comment: @TienKenji where are you getting this error? is it specified?

Comment: Error `Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.` when i use **@Html.Action("LastNewsPatial","News")**

Comment: @TienKenji Where are you putting this @Html.Action? in the index view or where?

Comment: yes, i putting in Index view at **Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `@Html.Partial("../Views/Shared/LastNewsPatial")`

The `..` instead of the `~`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here are missing the question
You use this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/News/LastNewsPatial.cshtml")
```

Which creates a partial view without a model. So in order for this to work you need to pass model.

```
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/News/LastNewsPatial.cshtml", your_model)
```

Your problem is not view related and you simply pass no object to the partial. How to do it is up to you. Do you want a Html.Partial or Html.Action? Depending on your needs.

P.S.

Use RenderPartial and RederAction they are better practices since Partial and Action return an HTML string where instead using render allows ASP.NET to write directly to the response stream.